# The undetected support of timestamp-query extension when using Chrome canary and WebGPU

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dotnetnuke, tensorflow.js, webgpu

### Description

Hi guys!

I am studying to use Tensorflow.js to run DNN in the Web browser with WebGPU feature.

#### Example #1

So, I first use the `MobileNet` example ([Source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/mobilenet)) of Tensorflow.js as an initial point. However, the example does not use the WebGPU backend of Tensorflow.js. So I modified the first few lines of `index.js` to use the WebGPU backend, as shown below:

```js
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgpu'
import { IMAGENET_CLASSES } from './imagenet_classes';
tf.setBackend('webgpu');
```

Then, following the `npm install` and `npm run watch`, the example indeed runs and could perform the DNN inference.

However, when I watch the terminal output of Chrome,  I see a warning that says

> This device doesn't support timestamp-query extension. Start Chrome browser with flag --disable-dawn-features=disallow_unsafe_apis then try again. Or zero will shown for the kernel time when profiling mode is enabled. Using performance.now is not workable for webgpu since it doesn't support synchronously to read data from GPU.

#### Example #2

Another example I tried is the performance benchmark between WebGPU and WebGL backend of Tensorflow.js in the official repo of Tensorflow.js. [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-backend-webgpu/perf)

I use `python3 -m http.server` to run a HTTP server in the `perf` folder, and run the benchmark.
However, the generated result shows that Tensorflow.js cannot get the execution time when running benchmarks on WebGPU. Moreover, the `support timestamp-query extension` warning is also appeared in the terminal of the browser.

### Execution environment of my experiments

I am using MacBook Pro M1 Max (with built-in GPU) + Google Chrome Canary (106.0.5205.0)

### Efforts I have tried

To make the `timestamp-query extension` work, following the instructions in the warning, I tried

```bash
./Google Chrome Canary --args --disable-dawn-features=disallow_unsafe_apis
```

However, this trick does not take any efforts.

So please you guys give me a hint that I can enable this feature?

Answer (score 0):

> This device doesn't support timestamp-query extension.

this is just an info message and not an error as `tfjs` does not need timestamp-query extension unless you're running in debug mode or running with `webgl1` (which you're clearly not)

it should not be printed in production mode, but then again `tfjs-backend-webgpu`  is an alpha version